MQL5 How to find lastest history order ticket?
I am writing an EA program using MQL5, and now I encounter a problem. I want to get the order number of the last closed order (as shown below, the target order number is 2308697611). I have tried many methods but cannot solve this problem.

The last attempt was to use the following code:
  HistorySelect(0, TimeCurrent());
  ulong ticket = HistoryDealGetTicket(HistoryDealsTotal() - 2);

But these two lines of code will only take effect if the positions are closed sequentially. If I close the positions randomly, I will not get the expected results.

The only way is enumerating on orders to find the last closed one.
And the function you used is getting the deal ticket not order ticket.

Using the following function, you can get the ticket number of last closed ticket in MQL5.
 int lastClosedTicket()
 {
  HistorySelect(0, TimeCurrent());
  uint total_trades = HistoryDealsTotal();
  ulong ticket_number = 0;
  for(int i =(int) total_trades - 1; i >= 0 ; --i)
    {
     if((ticket_number = HistoryDealGetTicket(i)) > 0)
       {
        return HistoryDealGetInteger(ticket_number, DEAL_TICKET)
       }
    }
 }

